# Always load newest js version from html embed

Tags: javascript, html, caching, sharepoint, embed

I have an embed webpart in sharepoint that showcases part of our available content, it's an html file that calls a script.js generated by an excel spreadsheet. The list of content changes often enough that multiple updates are pushed every week, often once a day.

Currently, it reads the .js correctly, but, if the file changes, it only reads the file again on a force reload.

I have tried adding the following code to my HTML:
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate"/>`
But it didn't change my situation.
Is there any way I can make it update without the user force reloading the page?
Ideally, only the HTML file would be edited, because the .js is generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a random number to the URL if you can.

Depending on how you generate the url in the first place the syntax may vary but something along the lines of

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'my.js?' + Math.random();
document.body.append(script);
```

So make a new script that you always load with this code, referencing to your real script (**my.js**) and load this script instead from your html file and you should be fine.

Comment: So my script src in the .aspx file would be this new .js and this one would call my.js, did I get that right?

Comment: Yes! You got it right!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a time stamp to the end of the JavaScript file URL to ensure that the browser always loads the latest version of the file.

```
<script src="path/to/your-script.js?t=<%= new Date().getTime() %>"></script>
```